# I am running 11.10 and want to know if this means I have USB 3.0

Tags: 11.10, usb

Does the following mean I have USB 3.0 on my PC?

```
    *-usb:0
         description: USB Controller
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
         ***version: 03***
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:16 ioport:40e0(size=32)
    *-usb:1
         description: USB Controller
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.1
         version: 03
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:21 ioport:40c0(size=32)
    *-usb:2
         description: USB Controller
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a.7
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.7
         version: 03
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:19 memory:d4505c00-d4505fff
```

Answer (score 1):

USB 3.0 uses a different driver than USB 2.0 (or 1.0). I think the 3.0 driver was called xhci---and your print out says driver=ehci, which was the 2.0 driver, but I don't remember the uhci driver.

Answer (score 0):

From what I [see here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/pci:2937:8086-USB), it's USB 2.0, and NOT 3.0. It would have definitely helped, if you mentioned your PC's make, model name etc.

Comment: And by the way, like you pointed out `***version: 03***` doesn't mean it's USB 3.0.